# Display CollectionFS images in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, gridfs, collectionfs

I'm having trouble retrieving stored images in GridFS (via CollectionFS) in my Angular controller. I subscribe to the meteor images:

```
$scope.images = $meteor.collectionFS(Images, false, Images);
```

then I upload them to the DB (which works)

```
$scope.uploadFile = function (files) {
    if (files.length > 0) {
        $scope.images.save( files[ 0 ] ).then( function( result ) {
            $scope.temp_winery.logo_src = result[ 0 ]._id._id;
        });
    }
};
```

but I want to be able to display them in my template... There seems to be no way to get the file objects that I want to call `.url()` on in the controller =(. Any help, ideas, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Alek,

After uploading to GridFs, it takes few seconds for image to be available .
Better option is to display image from local system first time.

FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function (file) {
            //var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
            //if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support
            selectedFile=file;
            if (/^image/.test( file.type)){ // only image file
                var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileRead//er
                reader.readAsDataURL(file); // read the local file

```
            reader.onloadend = function(e){ // set image data as background of div
                $('#productImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
            // $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not sure I can read your code. Also, I'm not using a filesystem, but storing directly into the DB.